# APEX 4.2 application login

Tags: oracle-apex

I have made a custom authentication routine in APEX 4.2 (package). The username I enter is converted to uppercase by APEX.

1. How can I prevent this?
2. How can customize the error messages i.e. "Invalid credentials"?

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
  APEX_AUTHENTICATION.LOGIN 
  ( 
    p_username IN VARCHAR2, 
    p_password IN VARCHAR2, 
    p_uppercase_username IN BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE  --If TRUE then p_username is converted to uppercase.
  );
```

source [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35127/apex_authentication.htm

1. atm no idea, but i'm looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter to control the case of the username.  See:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35127/apex_authentication.htm#AEAPI29157

This may work in apex 4.2.  On the Login Page of the application create a 'Before Header' process with this code:

```
if  apex_application.g_notification ='Invalid Login Credentials' then 
         apex_application.g_notification :='Your Altered Failed Login Message Here';
end if;
```